# trying to add click inside a re-usable directive to a element that may have different classes be different element and may have different text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

so here is the desire:  I need to add a directive to any html element and pass it an id.  This id is then used to populate a method that submits a form that has that id on the page.

Some devs have used a button some have used an anchor tag so I do not want the type of element to be part of the method.  It is intended to be highly re-usable.

I already have it working like this:

```
angular.module("App").directive("submitform", submitFormDirective);

function submitFormDirective(){
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
    var selector = $attrs.submitform;

    $element.on('click', function(){
      angular.element(selector).submit();
    });
  }
 }
}
```

But this uses jquery for the "on" method.  I want a fully angular method.  Or one that does not "fight" with the framework or use jquery.

The way I am doing it now I only need to apply this attribute to the element.  submit-form="#id-of-form"  And I would like to keep that functionality becasue it is clean and concise.  So I need to be able to add the ng-click to the element dynamically without using the limited template function which would limit the element being effected, inside the submitFormDirective.

The problem is that the $attrs.$set('ngClick', 'submitForm()') runs after the digest and $compile does not seem to work for me.  I need to be able to add the click and run the compile on only this element or use a different phase that will happen before the app compile will run.  But I have tried using compile to att the attr in conjunction with link adding the method to the scope to no avail.  Seems strange that you would not be able to add a event from a directive.  I must be missing something.  Can someone help?

Comment: i think the `$element.on` is fine. because its will use jqLite

Comment: Just to add to the above, it will use jqLite as long as you don't load jQuery in your app. If your app loads jQuery before Angular, then the methods of `$element` use jQuery. But either way, you are fine using `on()` :)

Comment: and for adding `ngClick` you can use `$timeout`.  `$timeout(function(){ $attrs.$set('ngClick', 'submitForm()')},100)`. this soultion fix my problem with digest

Comment: Sorry my bad, it does seem that "on()" is included in jqlite.  Raika or Sunil can you post n answer so I can accept and you get the points?